# load pictures from drawable folder for each record from Sqlite

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, drawable

I want to show the name of each country with corresponding flag in my android app.
Names of countries are stored in Sqlite database and the country flags are in drawable folders.
How can i load the country flags with corresponding country name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name your `drawables` as per the `country name or code` and use `getIdentifier(...)` method of Resources

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) here.

For Example,

```
int drawableId= getResources().getIdentifier("country_name", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

here pass the **name of the country** received from the `database`...

Then you can set it to your `Imageview` either by `setImageResource(..)` or `setDrawable(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Use getIdentifier has note: "use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name".

I think the other way is store your resource as a Hash Map with the key is your "country name" or "country code" and the value is linked to your image id (R.drawable.xxx).

Or you can store this image id in your table too.

Hope it help for you!

Comment: i said i have (R.drawable.CountryNames).
i need load picture by each record (for example name field)

Comment: In my case, I will cache their image Id (R.drawable.xxx) in my database table (country table).

Answer (score 0):

how about using xml instead of sqlite?

```
<array name="flags">
    <item>@drawable/flag_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/flag_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/flag_3</item>
</array>
```

and in java file:

```
TypedArray flags = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.flags);
int flag = flags.getResourceId(flag_item, 0);
```

you can get flag_item from your sqlite id column or even better you can make another array(string-array) and put country name in it with same order as flags arrays.